# Modifying SVG after it has been loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, svg

How would I modify an SVG file after it has been loaded by the browser, preferably through jquery? A simple example would be pressing a button and the color of the SVG element changes. Any documentation would help as well.

EDIT: This link helped a great deal:
w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SVG_in_HTML

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/ is the whole SVG spec and http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/svgdom.html is the SVG DOM.

Comment: Are there any simple examples? Do I have to use jquery.svg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "modify" SVG files (except by changing them on the server).  SVG files define a collection of SVG objects, each of which can be identified with an ID, if you wish.  These objects can be manipulated with JavaScript like you would any DOM element (e.g. setAttribute, etc).  Check http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#BasicDOMInterfaces for the DOM interfaces.  Notice that SVGElement extends Element, which is the basic DOM element type.

EDIT: simple example:

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="doSVGThing()" value="change">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect id="aRect" x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100"
            style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #9999ff"></rect>
</svg>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doSVGThing() {
            var r = document.getElementById('aRect');
            r.setAttribute('style', 'stroke: #00ff00; fill: #99ff99');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you can't change the color using javascript or jquery?

Comment: No, the opposite.  The link shows the DOM Interface, which is what you call using JavaScript.  You can use JavaScript to manipulate any property of the SVG object, which includes color.

Comment: Is there any simple, straightforward code illustrating how one loads an svg file and manipulates an element or two?

Comment: See my simple example above.

Comment: An element in a file, not an element in the html doc. I'm having difficulty finding specifically code for changing an SVG file.

Comment: An SVG file is simply a text file, you can edit it with your text editor.  If you mean on-the-fly modification of properties of SVG elements on your page, then your question may be how to embed an SVG file?  It is not simple if you want to manipulate the elements with JavaScript.   READ: http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SVG_in_HTML

Comment: Why cannot I simply import the svg file and modify as you did the rect?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30786/discussion-between-steve-h-and-anonymous)